# VBA Excel Formula with Dynamic Range And Variable

Tags: vba, excel

I want to do a dynamic sum formula in VBA and it's some how very difficult for me because I don't use well integer variables. 
the last row might change in the future and I need that the range will be dynamic.
thanks to those who will help me.

```
Sub SumColumns()
Sheets("data").Select
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Value = "sum"
Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 33
Selection.Font.Bold = True

    Dim LastCol As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    With Sheets("data")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[- " & LastRow & " + 1]C:R[-1]C)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B" & LastRow, "I" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

that is the line with the error:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[- " & LastRow & " + 1]C:R[-1]C)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the + 1 out of the quotes as that seems to be causing the problem and you need to deduct 1 otherwise you will be on row zero. The code below also removes your selects which are unnecessary and inefficient. And use your `LastCol` variable to determine across how many columns to copy the formula.

```
Sub SumColumns()

Dim LastCol As Long 'use Long rather than Integer
Dim LastRow As Long

With Sheets("data")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("A" & LastRow + 1)
        .Value = "sum"
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 33
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range("B" & LastRow + 1).Resize(, LastCol - 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & LastRow - 1 & "]C:R[-1]C)"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: can you show me how to borderaround the last line of sum?

Comment: sorry, gave it back what is fair is fair, used your code

Comment: You're entitled to award the answer to whoever you see fit. But really your last request was a separate question. FWIW I would use `BorderAround`  - look it up in Excel Help.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of many select portions and steam line code like below. Test it and see if this is what you are after.

```
    Sub SumColumns()
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With Sheets("data")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        With .Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(1, 0)
            .Value = "SUM"
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 33
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & LastRow - 1 & "]C:R[-1]C)"
        .Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).AutoFill Destination:=.Range("B" & LastRow, .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)), Type:=xlFillDefault
        .Range("A" & LastRow, .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Range("A" & LastRow, .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Borders.Weight = xlThin
    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: can you show me how to borderaround the last line of sum?

Comment: @RafaelOsipov I have edited the code. If it solves your issue then please mark this post as answer.